# Ruby Rspec Timer - refactoring solution

Tags: ruby, rspec, timer, refactoring

I solved TestFirst.org question 09_timer for Ruby Rspec testing.  My code works but I do not like it.  It is very long.  Any comments and/or suggestions for improving it would be greatly appreciated.  Please include an explanation to clarify any suggestions.  The goal was to create the Timer with an @seconds instance variable initialized to 0, and then return all values as a string with hours, minutes, seconds format: 00:00:00.  So 12 seconds => 00:00:12; 66 seconds => 00:01:06; and 4000 seconds => 01:06:40. 
Thank you.  Code below.

```
class Timer

    attr_accessor :seconds

    def initialize
      @seconds = 0
    end

    def padded(n)
      "0#{n}"
    end

    def time_string
      hours = @seconds/3600
      h_minutes = ((@seconds%3600)/60)
      minutes = @seconds/60
      m_seconds = @seconds%60
      second = @seconds
      seconds = ""

      if @seconds < 60
        if second < 10
          second =  padded(second)
        end
        seconds << "00:00:#{second}"
      elsif @seconds > 3600
        if hours < 10
          hours = padded(hours)
        end
        if h_minutes < 10
          h_minutes = padded(h_minutes)
        end
        if m_seconds < 10
          m_seconds = padded(m_seconds)
        end
        seconds << "#{hours}:#{h_minutes}:#{m_seconds}"
      else
        if minutes < 10
          minutes = padded(minutes)
        end
        if m_seconds < 10
          m_seconds = padded(m_seconds)
        end
        seconds << "00:#{minutes}:#{m_seconds}"
      end
      @seconds = seconds    
    end

end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several little things you can do to simplify your class, and a few large organizational changes.

1) Use `String#rjust` to pad the numbers:

```
def padded(n)
  "#{n}".rjust(2, '0')
end
```

This lets you apply it to every number, regardless or whether or not it already has two digits. As a consequence, you can get rid of all of the single-digit checks (`if h_minutes < 10`, etc).

2) Get rid of everything starting from the first if statement, as none of it is necessary. Just a few lines before, you have `hours = @seconds / 3600`, `h_minutes = ((@seconds%3600)/60)`, and `m_seconds = @seconds%60`, which are the only three values you need. Apply a simple map (for padding), and join with `":"` to arrive at your final string.

3) If you want an object-oriented approach, each of your hours/minutes/seconds variables could be a method, so you end up with something more like this:

```
class Timer
  attr_accessor :seconds
  def initialize
    @seconds = 0
  end

  def time_string
    [hours, minutes, m_seconds].map(&method(:padded)).join(":")
  end

  def hours
    seconds / 3600
  end

  def minutes
    (seconds % 3600)/60
  end

  def m_seconds
    (seconds % 60)
  end

  def padded(n)
    "#{n}".rjust(2, '0')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Zach. You just advanced my comprehension by weeks probably in one simple solution. One of my biggest concerns was with the oft repeating single checks that you nailed with a simple #rjust method. I had never even considered this. And I have never used #map in such a way, but thanks to you I now know of the Symbol#to_proc method. Big thumbs up.

Comment: Good to hear, jere.mac. `rjust` is one of those things in the standard library that comes up rarely, but is good to know when you need it. You'll find lots of things like that as you become more familiar with the language.